# Passing an arbitrary object to Coffeescript's anonymous function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

When I run the following Coffeescript code:

```
@sum = (x, y) -> x + y
```

I get this compiled Javascript:

```
(function() {

    this.sum = function(x, y) {
        return x + y;
    };

}).call(this);
```

Is there a way in Coffeescript to replace `this` in `.call(this)` with an arbitrary object like `myObject`or anything?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please add what's before/after `@sum = (x, y) -> x + y1`

Comment: No, this is actually my complete code. This is why I am asking how to change the `this` object, so that `sum()` is added to whatever object I want.

Comment: `(function() {` and `}).call(this);` are not compiled from `@sum = ...`. These are the result of running `coffee` without the `--bare` flag. [this](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%40sum%20%3D%20(x%2C%20y)%20-%3E%20x%20%2B%20y) is the actual result from compiling.

Comment: @RobW: I did not know that. I run `coffee -c example.coffee` in my console and I always get that anonymous function wrapper. I thought that was standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(function() {` and `}).call(this);` are not the result of compiling `@sum = ...`, but added by the `coffee` executable. [This](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3a%40sum%20%3D%20%28x%2C%20y%29%20-%3E%20x%20%2B%20y) is the actual result from compiling:

```
this.sum = function(x, y) {
  return x + y;
};
```

To get a different/desired output, run `coffee -b -c` (or `coffee -bc` or `coffee --bare --compile`) using [the following code](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3a%28-%3E%20%0A%20%20@sum%20=%20%28x,%20y%29%20-%3E%20x%20+%20y%0A%29.call%20@):

```
(-> 
  @sum = (x, y) -> x + y
).call WHATEVER
```

becomes

```
(function() {
  return this.sum = function(x, y) {
    return x + y;
  };
}).call(WHATEVER);
```

Comment: That is pretty much what I was looking for. Thanks! The flag does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
myobj.sum = (x, y) -> x + y
```

should get compiled to (**UPDATE**: See Rob W's answer for compile options) :-

```
myobj.sum = function(x, y) {
  return x + y;
};
```

Isn't that what you want? So further you can call it using `myobj.sum a, b`

Complete code..

```
myobj = {}
myobj.sum = (x, y) -> x + y

alert(myobj.sum 10,4)
```

Comment: No, I want to know whether that anonymous function can in any way be modified like for instance passing a different object than `this`

Comment: @Amberlamps: Why, is it because you want to extend the `sum` function into whatever object you pass? And then again, that anonymous function cannot ever be called again, so I don't see the point.